# $\gcd(a(X),\,a'(X))$ w.r.t. squarefree decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility, irreducible-polynomials

We are considering polynomials over a field $\mathbb{F}$. For $a \in \mathbb{F}[X]$, we have a *squarefree* decomposition
$$
a = \prod_{i=1}^k a_i^i
$$
where $\gcd(a_i,\,a_j) = 1$ for $i \neq j$ and the $a_i$ are squarefree. Existence is clear; simply group together all prime factors of the same multiplicity.

[At this webpage](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~rcorless/AM563/NOTES/Nov_16_95/node10.html) the following is said:

> If $a = \prod_{i=1}^k a_i^i$ is the square-free factorization of $a$, then it is clear that
>   $$
> a' = a \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{i\cdot a_i'}{a_i}
> $$
>   and hence that $c = \gcd(a, a')$ is
>   $$
> c = \prod_{i=2}^k a_i^{i-1}
> $$

I have some trouble verifying this - obviously, the given polynomial divides $\gcd(a,\,a')$, but how do I show divisibility in the other direction?
Writing $a'$ as 
$$
a' = \left( \prod_{i=2}^k a_i^{i-1} \right) \sum_{j=1}^k j \cdot a_j'\, \prod_{i=1,\,i\neq j}^k a_i 
$$

how can I show that there isn't some other prime factor $p\,\vert\,a$, such that

$$
p \,\mid\, \sum_{j=1}^k j \cdot a_j'\, \prod_{i=1,\,i\neq j}^k a_i
$$
i.e., that $\gcd(a,\,a')$ doesn't contain more prime factors?

I guess my main problem is that I want to know about the divisibility of a sum by some prime, but prime numbers intrinsically only directly relate to products, not sums...

I'm sorry if this question has some obviously easy answer I failed to see, I'm rather uninspired as of late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short trick, notice that $p$ would divide all the summands except at most one. Hence we are reduce to $p$ dividing one of the summands.

For more details, read the following:

> Just notice that if $p$ divides $a$, then $p$ divides some of the $a_i$. Let's say $p$ divides $a_{i_0}$. The only summand of $$\sum_{j=1}^k j \cdot a_j'\, \prod_{i=1,\,i\neq j}^k a_i$$ which do not have $a_{i_0}$ is $i_0 \cdot a_{i_0}'\, \prod_{i=1,\,i\neq i_0}^k a_i$. Thus $p$ divides the sum if and only if it divides $i_0 \cdot a_{i_0}'\, \prod_{i=1,\,i\neq i_0}^k a_i$. Even more, since the $a_i$ are pairwise coprime, $p$ does not divide $\prod_{i=1,\,i\neq i_0}^k a_i$ and so $p$ divides the sum if and only if it divides $a_{i_0}'$.
>
> Finally, this means that $p$ divides the sum if and only if $p$ divides both $a_{i_0}$ and $a_{i_0}'$. By an argument similar to the one above (with the factorization of $a_{i_0}$), this happens if and only if $p$ divides $p'$, but this is not possible as $p'$ has less degree.

Comment: Great, thank you! I was going into that direction but failed to make the crucial final thought :) I guess I would prefer a different explanation for $p$ not dividing both $a_{i_0}$ and $a_{i_0}'$: $a_{i_0}$ is squarefree, and hence $\gcd(a_{i_0},\,a_{i_0}')$ is trivial (wait, I just figured you gave the proof for that ; ) )